# Schengen days and Ireland

Tags: schengen, ireland, 90-180-visa-rules

I arrived to Ireland to study English on February 8th, 2014, and I got my student visa until April 7th, so I spent about 60 days without a visa.
I've read that Ireland and the UK are NOT in the Schengen agreement, and the days here should not be counted for Schengen (the Embassy of my country (Mexico) insist I must count my days there).

I read posts on forums, and I think I should leave the Schengen area for 3 months after I used my 90 days (I used only 60) in a period of 180 days. I left Ireland on June 17th, BUT I have a visa valid until February 2015. Do I still need to wait 3 months before reentering the Schengen area, or does this visa remove this period of 3 months?

I used the calculator of Schengen days on Planning mode (I need to go to Prague on August 25th, so I used this date), and I wrote my previous stay in the Schengen area (Ireland), and it says I can stay until November 25th, but I don't know if this is right or not.

Comment: The Mexican embassy in Ireland? They can say whatever they want, it does not make it true. Days in Ireland definitely do not count.

Answer (score 6):

The Mexican embassy is wrong, days in Ireland do not count toward the 90-day limit in the Schengen area. There are subtle rules on how days are counted and how the limit works with visas from Schengen member states but since Ireland is not in the Schengen area, it does not make sense to consider all this. On August 25, you will simply enter the Schengen area for the first time with a full 90 days of potential stay.

Comment: Any details or reference for those subtle rules?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I am referring to the rolling 180-day period and the fact that stays under a long-stay visa do not count towards the 90-day limit. There are many questions about that in the archive.